# Understanding output of xattr -p com.apple.quarantine

Tags: macos, terminal, xattr

The other day I was messing with some files that had the extended attribute *com.apple.quarantine* on them. I am aware of its purpose, but I have always been curious what the properties below meant when you output its values.

E.g. when I typed in

`xattr -p com.apple.quarantine xmlrpc.php`

for a file that has the said xattr, I get output like this:

`0083;59b926ad;Safari.app;55847AA4-5562-42A2-89A7-8FAD394B455C`

What do the first 4 digits represent? i.e. `0083` Google hasn't brought up anything good and there are a few guides I found from users also trying to figure out what these numbers precisely represent.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As you're probably already aware, the quarantine flags are set when an agent (browser, mail client etc) saves a file to your machine. This is responsible for the warning that appears when you first try to open an application that was downloaded from the internet.

All this information is stored and there's a complete history for every user.

The first 4 digits are a set of flags that I expect are defined in `quarantine.h`, which appears to be a private header included in [copyfile.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/copyfile/copyfile-138/copyfile.c.auto.html), within Apple's open source code.

These flags represent states, such as whether the file is quarantined or not.

On closer analysis, the kernel extension `quarantine.kext` is responsible for handling this and upon disassembly, we can see the function `quarantine_get_flags`.

Here's just a snippet of the disassembled kext
[image]

Note the formatting of the xattr output's first 4 flags with **_sscanf(rbx, "%04x;") == 0x1)**

This calls `quarantine_get_info`.

[image]

We can see here that the flags denote various states of the file on the system, with vfs being the Virtual File System and vnode is the basic representation structure of a file.

As for the rest of the `xattr` output, each user has a local `sqlite3`database that keeps a record of every item downloaded. Its location is

> ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.QuarantineEventsV2

The database has just one table `LSQuarantineEvent`. You can read all the data by using the `sqlite3` command in the terminal

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.QuarantineEventsV2 "select * from LSQuarantineEvent;"
```

If you filter the results (grep or alternative) you'll be able to match up the GUID that makes up the latter part of the `xattr` output and you'll see all the information about that particular download, including which agent was responsible for downloading the file and even the URL from where it was retrieved.

Comment: In Ventura, the DB still exists at that path (Preferences, not Settings) and it still contains LSQuarantineEvent but that table appears to be empty.

Comment: @WGroleau sounds like something has cleared it for you, it's still populated for me on macOS 13.5.2 and I can see that Microsoft Teams is particularly noisy with its updater!